Infinite group with non-trivial finite commutator subgroup.
I wonder if there are any infinite groups with non-trivial finite commutator subgroup. Thanks!
Edit: I have tried some representations, for example, the free group of rank $2$ modulo some relations, but It is hard to make $G$ infinite and $[G,G]$ finite simultanously. (e.g. $D_\infty$ has infinite commutator subgroup.:(

Remark: In $1904$, Schur proved that an arbitrary group $G$ with $G/Z(G)$ finite has a finite commutator group.

I would add the assumption that the group should be indecomposable. Maybe more. Otherwise it's boring.

Hint: Try for example $G=S_3\times\mathbb{Z}$.

Thank you! I almost forget the fact that $[G,G]$ is the largest normal subgroup with Abelian quotient!

@Zoudelong Smallest normal subgroup, not largest. And it's a very useful fact. It allows to get information about $[G,G]$ without computing commutators.
